# Serializing Dataset And Relationships Into XML with C#

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I need some opinions/direction on the following issue:

I need a way to serialize rows from several tables into XML where the values are expressed as attributes, not tags.  I've started digging into the dataset's WriteXML method but I'm not sure I can customize that XML the way I need it.  It would be in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Import operatorName="ABC123">
    <customers>
        <customer id="12345" firstName="Abraham" lastName="Lincoln" dob="02/12/1809">
            <addresses>
                <address city="the city" state="the state" zip="12345" street="the street">
                <address city="the city 2" state="the state 2" zip="54321" street="another street">
            </addresses>
            <customerEncounters>
                <customerEncounter id="797979" date="01/01/2013" location="somewhere"> 
                    <customerRepresentative name="The Dude">
                    <mechanic name="Mr. Mechanic"> 
                </customerEncounter>
            </customerEncounters>
            <customerEncounters>
                <customerEncounter id="888888" date="01/15/2013" location="somewhere else"> 
                    <customerRepresentative name="The Dude">
                    <mechanic name="Mr. Mechanic"> 
                </customerEncounter>
            </customerEncounters>
        </customer>
        <customer>
           ....
        </customer>
    </customers>
</Import>
```

Put simply, the tables are as follows:

**Customers**
ID
Fname
Lname
DOB

**CustomerAddress**
ID 
CustomerID
Street
City
State
Zip

**Encounter**
ID
CustomerID
Date
Location
MechanicID
CustRepID

**Mechanics**
ID
Name

**CustomerRepresentatives**
ID
Name

There can be many addresses and encounters per customer.

Per data grab, I won't be getting a ton of customers (50 or fewer).  Is this even possible with a dataset?  Or is there a more resource-friendly way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you describe the tables involved and is this xml the desired format. I assume your "it would be in the following format" comment is referring to the required output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, perhaps the following MSDN article will be useful:

[Mapping Columns to XML Elements, Attributes, and Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx8h06sz.aspx)

It explains how you can define how each `DataColumn` values in your `DataTables` would be serialized.

Comment: Thanks, I think this will get me there.